# Не записываются данные с формы в таблицу PHPadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Сделал банальную форму для ввода данных - ничего не происходит.
Ошибки не выскакивают.
Просто ничего не идет в таблицу и все.

Локальный сервер - XAMPP

Фрагмент кода:

```
<?php


    if(count($_POST) > 0) {
      $name = trim($_POST['name']);
      $phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
      $dt = date("Y-m-d H:i");

        if (strlen($name) < 2) {
          $msg = 'Нужно имя по-длинее';
        }
          elseif (strlen($phone) < 7) {
            $msg = 'Не умее звонить на номера короче 7 цифр';
          }
            else {

              $msg = 'Вашя Заявка принята';
              $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost,dbname=site', 'root', '');
              $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO bids (name,phone) VALUES(:name, :phone)");
              $values = ['name' => $name, 'phone' => $phone];
              $query->execute($values);

              $msg = 'Вашя Заявка принята';
            }
          }
          else {
            $name = '';
            $phone = '';
            $msg = 'Заполни все поля';
          }
```

Comment: Так ты тут и не проверяешь ничего на ошибки, с чего бы им выскакивать.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)